Error with H2O in R - No active connection to an H2O cluster despite "Successful Connection"
I would like to switch the parsinp engine to h2o and use h2o and agua packages to fit models. The following code is from the standard help site.
With tune::tune_grid, I bump into the "Warning: All models failed ...", which is due to "Error in h2o.getConnection(): No active connection to an H2O cluster ...". Although the output of h2o.getConnection() immediately before and after tune_grid suggest everything should be OK.
library(ggplot2)
library(tidymodels)
library(agua)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'agua'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:workflowsets':
#> 
#>     rank_results
library(h2o)
#> 
#> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#> 
#> Your next step is to start H2O:
#>     > h2o.init()
#> 
#> For H2O package documentation, ask for help:
#>     > ??h2o
#> 
#> After starting H2O, you can use the Web UI at http://localhost:54321
#> For more information visit https://docs.h2o.ai
#> 
#> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'h2o'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     cor, sd, var
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     %*%, %in%, &&, ||, apply, as.factor, as.numeric, colnames,
#>     colnames<-, ifelse, is.character, is.factor, is.numeric, log,
#>     log10, log1p, log2, round, signif, trunc

doParallel::registerDoParallel()

h2o::h2o.init()
#>  Connection successful!
#> 
#> R is connected to the H2O cluster: 
#>     H2O cluster uptime:         50 minutes 51 seconds 
#>     H2O cluster timezone:       America/New_York 
#>     H2O data parsing timezone:  UTC 
#>     H2O cluster version:        3.46.0.5 
#>     H2O cluster version age:    16 days 
#>     H2O cluster name:           H2O_started_from_R_siava_dqu656 
#>     H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
#>     H2O cluster total memory:   13.28 GB 
#>     H2O cluster total cores:    32 
#>     H2O cluster allowed cores:  32 
#>     H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE 
#>     H2O Connection ip:          localhost 
#>     H2O Connection port:        54321 
#>     H2O Connection proxy:       NA 
#>     H2O Internal Security:      FALSE 
#>     R Version:                  R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14 ucrt)
h2o::h2o.connect()
#>  Connection successful!
#> 
#> R is connected to the H2O cluster: 
#>     H2O cluster uptime:         50 minutes 54 seconds 
#>     H2O cluster timezone:       America/New_York 
#>     H2O data parsing timezone:  UTC 
#>     H2O cluster version:        3.46.0.5 
#>     H2O cluster version age:    16 days 
#>     H2O cluster name:           H2O_started_from_R_siava_dqu656 
#>     H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
#>     H2O cluster total memory:   13.28 GB 
#>     H2O cluster total cores:    32 
#>     H2O cluster allowed cores:  32 
#>     H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE 
#>     H2O Connection ip:          localhost 
#>     H2O Connection port:        54321 
#>     H2O Connection proxy:       NA 
#>     H2O Internal Security:      FALSE 
#>     R Version:                  R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14 ucrt)
h2o::h2o.getConnection()
#> IP Address: localhost 
#> Port      : 54321 
#> Name      : NA 
#> Session ID: _sid_b5d8 
#> Key Count : 0

data(ames)

set.seed(4595)
data_split <- ames |>
  mutate(Sale_Price = log10(Sale_Price)) |>
  initial_split(strata = Sale_Price)
ames_train <- training(data_split)
ames_test <- testing(data_split)
cv_splits <- vfold_cv(ames_train, v = 10, strata = Sale_Price)

ames_rec <-
  recipe(Sale_Price ~ Gr_Liv_Area + Longitude + Latitude, data = ames_train) |>
  step_log(Gr_Liv_Area, base = 10) |>
  step_ns(Longitude, deg_free = tune("long df")) |>
  step_ns(Latitude, deg_free = tune("lat df"))

lm_mod <- linear_reg(penalty = tune()) |>
  set_engine("h2o")

lm_wflow <- workflow() |>
  add_model(lm_mod) |>
  add_recipe(ames_rec)

grid <- lm_wflow |>
  extract_parameter_set_dials() |>
  grid_regular(levels = 5)

h2o.getConnection()
#> IP Address: localhost 
#> Port      : 54321 
#> Name      : NA 
#> Session ID: _sid_b5d8 
#> Key Count : 0

ames_res <- tune_grid(
  lm_wflow,
  resamples = cv_splits,
  grid = grid,
  control = control_grid(save_pred = TRUE,
                         backend_options = agua_backend_options(parallelism = 5))
)
#> Warning: All models failed. Run `show_notes(.Last.tune.result)` for more
#> information.

h2o.getConnection()
#> IP Address: localhost 
#> Port      : 54321 
#> Name      : NA 
#> Session ID: _sid_b5d8 
#> Key Count : 0

agua::h2o_running(verbose = FALSE)
#> [1] TRUE

show_notes(.Last.tune.result)
#> unique notes:
#> ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Error in h2o.getConnection(): No active connection to an H2O cluster. Did you run `h2o.init()` ?
Created on 2024-09-15 with reprex v2.1.1

Latest RStudio is run with both normal and administrative privileges (same issue - although we should not need admin rights) on Windows 11 Pro x64 machine. JRE (1.8.0_421) and JDK (22) are installed, and all Java paths (JRE_HOME, JDK_HOME, JAVA_HOME = JRE_HOME) are all A-OK! I went so-far as to use rJava to manually initialize a Java VM instance with no effect. The command demo(h2o.kmeans) runs without a problem and produces expected results.
The only other thing of note is that running agua::h2o_start() produces weird output that it should not be. I get "permission denied error" on user folder which should be accessible even without admin rights (folder-access issue is the same with h2o package) and I get "no Java error" that shouldn't be there.
Warning message:
JAVA not found, H2O may take minutes trying to connect. 

Could this be the root of the issue: "h2o cluster connection is there as far as h2o package is concerned but agua (which adds supports for tidymodels) does not recognize Java and the existing h2o connection"?!

Looks like the "JAVA not found" error from agua::h2o_start() is coming from a call to Sys.which("java"). What output do you see in that case? Do you see different output in a terminal with which java? I might focus on making sure the system knows where to find java using which as my first debugging route.
Also, some diagnostic messages read:
h2o::h2o.init()
#> Note:  In case of errors look at the following log files:
#>     C:\Users\siava\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp08HkaV\filec5072151a2b/h2o_siava_started_from_r.out
#>     C:\Users\siava\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp08HkaV\filec50cc92881/h2o_siava_started_from_r.err

Could you re-run h2o::h2o.init(), note the log files shown in the output, attempt to run your tuning code, and then paste the log file contents here?
(For future readers, further discussion of this issue at https://github.com/tidymodels/agua/issues/57).

Turns out this user had cluster <- parallel::makeCluster(...) in their .Rprofile, setting up tidymodels parallelism support.
agua_backend_options(parallelism = 5) tells agua to use H2O's within-model parallelism, distributing computations for a single model across 5 cores. cluster <- parallel::makeCluster(...) tells tidymodels to use its across-model parallelism, fitting n_models/n_cores models per core across n_cores cores. Setting both of these is an example of "nested parallelism," and is unsupported by agua, as connections to H2O can't be serialized and shipped off to cluster workers. So, either agua_backend_options(parallelism = 5) or cluster <- parallel::makeCluster(...) will work, but not both at the same time.

Solved. It doesn't have anything to do with R/H2O version, Java, or Linux/Windows. It was right there but strangely I didn't see the obvious: You need to have a cluster object and every node needs to be initialized. The future package doesn't have a function to return the cluster object nor the ability to initialize nodes properly with complex code, but the parallel package does.
To use the model parallelism for tidymodels and data parallelism for h2o and agua, you need to mix-up parallel, future, and doFuture packages. The parallel packages is used to detect cores, make a cluster, and then load-up and initialize every node. The future and doFuture packages are used to plan a future and register the for.each backend, which is required to enable model-parallelism in tidymodels. Tidymodels specifically uses the future package while agua can work with future, parallel, etc (please correct if wrong).
# H2O for machine learning
library(h2o)

# Initialize local H2O server and start
local_h2o <- h2o::h2o.init(startH2O = TRUE)
local_h2o |> print()

# The agua package provides tidymodels interface to the H2O platform and the
# H2O R package
library(agua)

# Adaptive Parallelism - Decided by H2O
h2o_thread_spec <- agua::agua_backend_options(parallelism = 0)

# To be used when using grid search, racing, or any of the iterative search
# methods in tidymodels.
grid_ctrl <- tune::control_grid(
  allow_par = TRUE,
  save_pred = TRUE,
  save_workflow = TRUE,
  event_level = "second",
  # chooses between "resamples" and "everything" automatically
  parallel_over = NULL,
  backend_options = h2o_thread_spec
)

# Parallel computation libraries
library(future)
library(doFuture)

# Speed up computation with parrallel processing (optional)
n_cores <- parallel::detectCores(logical = TRUE) 
cluster <- parallel::makeCluster(spec = n_cores)
doFuture::registerDoFuture()
strategy <- future::plan(strategy = future::cluster, workers = cluster)

# load, initialize, and check status of h2o on a cluster node
node_h2o_init <- function() {
  library(h2o)
  library(agua)

  # doesn't start a new server if you've already started one
  cluster_init <- h2o.init(startH2O = FALSE)

  c(cluster_init = cluster_init, cluster_status = h2o.clusterIsUp())
}

# initialize and check each node
cluster |>
  parallel::clusterCall(cl = _, fun = node_h2o_init) |>
  purr::list_c()

